# Add Solid and Light Font Awesome Pro to React site

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I have a React website, the FontAwesome Pro work without problem. How can I add a second coffee icon, but from the `pro-light-svg-icons` instead of the `pro-duotone-svg-icons`?

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome" 
import { faTwitter } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"
import { faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons"

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <p>Twitter icon goes her : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />
        </p>  
      </Layout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out on the FAQ section here https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react
`import { faCoffee as fasFaCoffee } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons' import { faCoffee as farFaCoffee } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'`